# Lookup value in dictionary between range pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a "lookup" table formatted as such:

```
Min | Max | Val
  1 |  99 | "Principal"
100 | 199 | "Partner"
... | ... | ...
```

There is a `CURRENT_POINTS` series in my dataframe that is between Min or Max (inclusive).

**Question**: how do I create a `VAL` column that is based on the above lookup table? My initial thought was to use `df.lookup`, but there are 800K rows in `df` and so the two tables are not equally sized.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method.

Assuming you have the following DFs:

```
In [187]: lkp
Out[187]:
   Min  Max  Val
0    1   99  AAA
1  100  199  BBB
2  200  299  CCC
3  300  399  DDD

In [188]: df
Out[188]:
   CURRENT_POINTS
0              55
1              10
2              20
3             144
4             194
5             143
6             397
7             233
8             128
9             215
```

Using `cut()` method we can produce a new column of a `category` dtype, which might save a lot of memory:

```
In [189]: df['Val'] = pd.cut(df.CURRENT_POINTS,
     ...:                    bins=[0] + lkp[['Min','Max']].stack()[1::2].tolist(),
     ...:                    labels=lkp.Val.tolist())
     ...:

In [190]: df
Out[190]:
   CURRENT_POINTS  Val
0              55  AAA
1              10  AAA
2              20  AAA
3             144  BBB
4             194  BBB
5             143  BBB
6             397  DDD
7             233  CCC
8             128  BBB
9             215  CCC

In [191]: df.dtypes
Out[191]:
CURRENT_POINTS       int32
Val               category
dtype: object
```

Category dtype can save a lot of memory:

```
In [192]: big = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [193]: big.shape
Out[193]: (1000000, 2)

In [194]: big['str_col'] = 'AAA'

In [198]: big.dtypes
Out[198]:
CURRENT_POINTS       int32
Val               category
str_col             object
dtype: object

In [195]: big.memory_usage()
Out[195]:
Index                  80
CURRENT_POINTS    4000000
Val               1000032     # <--- `category` column takes 1 byte per row (plus 32 bytes overhead)
str_col           8000000

In [197]: big.head()
Out[197]:
   CURRENT_POINTS  Val str_col
0              55  AAA     AAA
1              10  AAA     AAA
2              20  AAA     AAA
3             144  BBB     AAA
4             194  BBB     AAA
```

NOTE: pay attention at memory usage for the `category` column `Val` and for the `str_col` column (dtype: `object`)

Explanation:

bins:

```
In [199]: lkp[['Min','Max']]
Out[199]:
   Min  Max
0    1   99
1  100  199
2  200  299
3  300  399

In [200]: lkp[['Min','Max']].stack()
Out[200]:
0  Min      1
   Max     99
1  Min    100
   Max    199
2  Min    200
   Max    299
3  Min    300
   Max    399
dtype: int64

In [201]: lkp[['Min','Max']].stack()[1::2].tolist()
Out[201]: [99, 199, 299, 399]

In [202]: [0] + lkp[['Min','Max']].stack()[1::2].tolist()
Out[202]: [0, 99, 199, 299, 399]
```

labels:

```
In [203]: lkp.Val.tolist()
Out[203]: ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

NOTE: `lkp` must be sorted by `['Min', 'Max']` before using it for `bins` and `labels`.

Here is a small demo for sorting:

```
In [2]: lkp
Out[2]:
   Min  Max  Val
0  300  399  DDD
1  100  199  BBB
2    1   99  AAA
3  200  299  CCC

In [4]: lkp = lkp.sort_values(['Min','Max'])

In [5]: lkp
Out[5]:
   Min  Max  Val
2    1   99  AAA
1  100  199  BBB
3  200  299  CCC
0  300  399  DDD
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Would I then just `as.type(str)` to the `Val` column created above to reduce memory load?

Comment: @user791411, you are welcome! No, you want to keep it as `category` - it's just a "tuned" string dtype. I've added `str_col` in order to show the difference in memory usage

Comment: OK thanks! **Question**: I received an error message saying `"ValueError: bins must increase monotonically."` How should I change the code?

Comment: @user791411, as i wrote at the end of my answer - the lookup DF must be sorted...

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!

Comment: I get "ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')" when I try to implement this

Comment: @Mandi, i would recommend you to open a new question and post there a small reproducible sample data set, which would help us to reproduce your error... You can also check yourself that the posted solution is working properly - just create datasets from the answer using `pd.read_clipboard()` function and try to run the same code.